# PHP Get latest tweets in json format

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using the following code to parse the latest tweets from a twitter account:

```
    $host = "http://search.twitter.com";
    $filename = "/search.json";

    $opts = array('http' => array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
    ));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $search = "mashable";
    $search = str_replace(" ", "%20", $search);
    $count = "10";

    $a = "$host$filename?q=$search&rpp=$count&include_entities=true";
    echo "$a\n";
    $json = file_get_contents($a, false, $context);

    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    $id = $obj['results'][0]['id'];
    $tweet = $obj['results'][0]['text'];
    $user = $obj['results'][0]['from_user'];
    $to_user = $obj['results'][0]['to_user'];
    $media_url = $obj['results'][0]['media_url'];

    #echo $json;
    echo "<br /><br />";
    echo "searching for $search\n tweet count: $count\n";
    echo "<br /><br /><b>tweets</b><br />";
    echo "tweet_id: $id <br />";
    echo "user: $user <br />";
    echo "Tweet: $tweet<br />";
    echo "to_user: $to_user <br />";
    echo "media: $media_url";
    echo ""

?>
```

I would like to extract the following values:
- username (sender)
- tweet (text)
- to user (if is reply)
- media attachments (pictures)

The code is working but for some reason I only receive the latest tweet instead of the number ($count) value. I also can't receive the media_url value of a tweet. My question is: how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to receive the media_url parameter of each tweet:

```
$media_url = $result['entities']['media'][0]['media_url']
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to loop around the results to get all the results instead of one of them, for example:

```
$host = "http://search.twitter.com";
$filename = "/search.json";

$opts = array('http' => array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$search = "mashable";
$search = str_replace(" ", "%20", $search);
$count = "10";

$a = "$host$filename?q=$search&rpp=$count&include_entities=true";
echo "$a\n";
$json = file_get_contents($a, false, $context);

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($obj['results'] as $index => $result) {
    $id = $result['id'];
    $tweet = $result['text'];
    $user = $result['from_user'];
    $to_user = $result['to_user'];
    $media_url = $result['media_url'];

    #echo $json;
    echo "<br /><br />";
    echo "searching for $search\n tweet count: $count\n";
    echo "<br /><br /><b>tweets</b><br />";
    echo "tweet_id: $id <br />";
    echo "user: $user <br />";
    echo "Tweet: $tweet<br />";
    echo "to_user: $to_user <br />";
    echo "media: $media_url";
    echo "";
}
```

Also, when I did a `print_r($obj);` I couldn't see any `media_url` value in there - doesn't look like Twitter is returning that, which is why you can't access it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If you use the code with the 'GettyImages' you 'll see the parameter media_url in the second tweet.